# PHP uploading files: failed to get error message

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload files through the PHP function **move_uploaded_file** and this is what I have so far:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], iconv("UTF-8","big5",$target_file))) {
    return true;
} 
else {
    echo "Not uploaded because of error #".$file["error"];
    exit(0);
    return false;
}
```

As for `$target_file`, it is the location I'd like to upload my files, which is currently **stu_feedback/105502504/feedback_20180910.pdf**.
Yet, the files are all failed to be uploaded, which obviously goes to the **else** part.
But when I wanted to echo the error message, it only shows **0**.

I use Filezilla Client. I have tested on my localhost and it could upload files correctly. 
Does anyone know what actually happened?

Comment: As I understood, the script is working on your localhost, but on your host it's not uploading? Did you check write permissions? (chmod)

Comment: where to store `$file["error"]` ?

Comment: `$file['error']` will only show errors that occured when uploading to the server, not those when moving from tmp to target folder.

Comment: @D.Dimitrov Since I am doing a remote work, where should I type chmod to test the permission of moving a file to folder? :(

Comment: sudo chmod 755 -R /folder , I'd not recommend you to set 777 permissions.

Comment: @D.Dimitrov I just found that the folder I plan to store things in is a directory, does this leads to the problem (can not upload)?

Comment: Did you check the permissions of your upload target folder/directory?

Comment: @D.Dimitrov It works like magic! Seems to be the permission problem. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I see some problems on this part :

1. Add `enctype` to the form `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`;
2. Be sure that the folder where you want to move files are permissions (chmod -R /folder_name 777)
3. Try to put in a try catch you code something like :

   ```
   try{
       if (move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], iconv("UTF- 8","big5",$target_file))) {
           return true;
       } 
       else {
         echo "Not uploaded because of error #".$file["error"];
         //exit(0);
         return false;
       }
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
        die();
    }
   ```

Comment: @George To test a folder's permission, should I just type chmod -R/folder_name 777 on ssh?